# bigquery url decode

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an easy way to do URL decoding within the BigQuery query language? I'm working with a table that has a column containing URL-encoded strings in some values. For example:

```
http://xyz.com/example.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fhello%3Fv%3D12345&foo=bar&abc=xyz
```

I extract the "url" parameter like so:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(column_name, "url=([^&]+)") as url 
from [mydataset.mytable]
```

which gives me:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fhello%3Fv%3D12345
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
SELECT URL_DECODE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(column_name, "url=([^&]+)")) as url 
from [mydataset.mytable]
```

thereby returning:

```
http://www.example.com/hello?v=12345
```

I would like to avoid using multiple REGEXP_REPLACE() statements (replacing %20, %3A, etc...) if possible.

Ideas?

Answer (score 20):

Below is built on top of @sigpwned answer, but slightly refactored and wrapped with SQL UDF (which has no limitation that JS UDF has so safe to use)

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION URLDECODE(url STRING) AS ((
  SELECT SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(
        IF(STARTS_WITH(y, '%'), FROM_HEX(SUBSTR(y, 2)), CAST(y AS BYTES)) ORDER BY i
      ), b''))
  FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r"%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[^%]+")) AS y WITH OFFSET AS i 
));
SELECT 
  column_name, 
  URLDECODE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(column_name, "url=([^&]+)")) AS url
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

can be tested with example from question as below

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION URLDECODE(url STRING) AS ((
  SELECT SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(
        IF(STARTS_WITH(y, '%'), FROM_HEX(SUBSTR(y, 2)), CAST(y AS BYTES)) ORDER BY i
      ), b''))
  FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r"%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[^%]+")) AS y WITH OFFSET AS i 
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'http://example.com/example.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fhello%3Fv%3D12345&foo=bar&abc=xyz' column_name
)
SELECT 
  URLDECODE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(column_name, "url=([^&]+)")) AS url,
  column_name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```sql
Row url                                     column_name  
1   http://www.example.com/hello?v=12345    http://example.com/example.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fhello%3Fv%3D12345&foo=bar&abc=xyz
```

> Update with further quite optimized SQL UDF

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION URLDECODE(url STRING) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(
    IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(y, r'^%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}'), 
      SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(FROM_HEX(REPLACE(y, '%', ''))), y), '' 
    ORDER BY i
    )
  FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(url, r"%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(?:%[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*|[^%]+")) y
  WITH OFFSET AS i 
));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a good feature request, but currently there is no built in BigQuery function that provides URL decoding.

Comment: Is there a link to this feature request?

Answer (score 4):

One more workaround is using a user-defined function.

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION URL_DECODE(enc STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { 
    return decodeURI(enc);;
  } catch (e) { return null }
  return null;
""";

SELECT ven_session, 
  URL_DECODE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(para,r'&kw=(\w|[^&]*)')) AS q
FROM raas_system.weblog_20170327 
WHERE para like '%&kw=%'
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This will problem when you want to store query as view

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone here that `URLDECODE` should be a native function. However, until that happens, it is possible to write a "native" `URLDECODE`:

```sql
SELECT id, SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ps, b'')) FROM (SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(y, r"^%") THEN FROM_HEX(SUBSTR(y, 2))
    ELSE CAST(y AS bytes)
  END ORDER BY i) AS ps
  FROM (SELECT x AS id, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(x, r"%[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|[^%]+") AS element FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['domodossola%e2%80%93locarno railway', 'gabu%c5%82t%c3%b3w']) AS x) AS x
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(x.element) AS y WITH OFFSET AS i GROUP BY id);
```

In this example, I've tried and tested the implementation with a couple of percent-encoded page names from Wikipedia as the input. It should work with your input, too.

Obviously, this is extremely unwieldly! For that reason, I'd suggest building a materialized join table, or wrapping this in a view, rather than using this expression "naked" in your query. However, it does appear to get the job done, and it doesn't hit the UDF limits.

EDIT: [@MikhailBerylyant's post below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831391/bigquery-url-decode/51218333#51218333) has wrapped this cumbersome implementation into a nice, tidy little SQL UDF. That's a much better way to handle this!

Comment: Thank you! Nice packaging as a SQL UDF! Edited.