# Working with url-encoded values in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I work with gzipped log files which contain url-encoded columns. (a space character is encoded as "%20", etc).

My plan was to import these files directly from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery.

I did not find any option in the [Load config](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs?hl=fr#importing) to automatically decode values during the import.

I guess you wouldn't advice using a series of [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference?hl=fr#regularexpressionfunctions) in all my queries.

Any idea which would avoid parsing all the logs and escape all these characters before importing them to BigQuery (which would be dangerous if one of them is the separator) ?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831391/bigquery-url-decode, this is not available now in bigquery.

Comment: As requested by BigQuery developers, we've started a public issue tracker to both collect feature requests, as well as allow a place to report bugs. We have this request as our first feature request: http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=1 "Star" the issue to vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you already ended up with something like below :o)

```
SELECT url FROM
js(
  (SELECT url FROM 
    (SELECT 'http://example.com/query?q=my%20query%20string' AS url), 
    (SELECT 'http://example.com/query?q=your%20query%20string' AS url), 
    (SELECT 'http://example.com/query?q=his%20query%20string' AS url)
  ),
  // Input columns.
  url,
  // Output schema.
  "[
  {name: 'url', type:'string'}]",
  // The function.
  "function(r, emit) { 
    var url  = decodeURI(r.url);
    emit({
      url: url
    });
  }"
)
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer if for Legacy SQL.

For Standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION DECODE_URI_COMPONENT(path STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
if (path == null) return null;
try {
  return decodeURIComponent(path);
} catch (e) {
  return path;
}
""";

WITH source AS (SELECT "/work.json?myfield=R%C3%A9gions%2CSport" AS path)
SELECT DECODE_URI_COMPONENT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(path, r"[?&]myfield=([^&]+)")) AS myfield FROM source
```

This returns:

```
 myfield
---------------
 Régions,Sport
```